# ImageLoader or IntentService with Caching in android

Tags: android, caching, intentservice, universal-image-loader

### In my application I am trying to download images from server and Display it in listview

---

The image sizes will be 1*1(inches)

---

**In two ways we can achieve this**::

- Using image loader
- Using Intent Service

---

**My Questions**::

- Which one is faster
- My application will download around 100 to 500 images from server,
  Can i cache these images or should i store it in a internal storage
  as file.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [imageloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) It's faster and also option get image from catch.